# How to set for laptop to use internal graphic card while playing flash videos?

Tags: flash-player, integrated-graphics

I want to use intel hd4000 while watching videos on youtube or similar web sites. Because external gt740m needs more power and this causes to lower battery life.

How to set that ?

I'm using windows 8. I've tried to disable this option:

[image: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/images/display_en.gif]

Comment: which operating system are you using? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @D0rf added what you've asked.

Comment: which browser you are using?some browsers have built-in support to use graphic card